# Мой код не выводится на сайте,ошибок нет

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            let Ya = promt('Как тебя зовут?');
            let Freind  = promt('Как зовут твоего друга?');
            alert('Привет!'); 
        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: что значит 'не выводится на сайте'?

Comment: как ты узнал, что "ошибок нет"?

Comment: не реагирует на код,просто пустая страница

Comment: окей, как ты узнал что ошибок нет? я вот вижу и даже проверил. А ты?

Comment: В VScode ошибок нет,в консоли тоже.

Comment: неправда. в консоли есть ошибки

Comment: все увидел,благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы хотели, чтобы всплывало окошко с вводом значений для JS-переменных, то Вы имели в виду функцию [prom***p***t()](https://learn.javascript.ru/alert-prompt-confirm#prompt). Вы просто не написали букву 'p' для всех строк, отсюда и ошибка.